# What domain redirection type do I need?

Tags: dns, subdomain, redirect

I have domain a.com on one provider, webspace and domain b.com on another, where the target site is hosted.

What settings, what type of redirection do I need, what do I have to do, to get the following working:

When you go on a.com, "a.com" stays in the address bar. When come from a.com and browse through the subpages of b.com, like "b.com/sub", the address bar shows "a.com/sub".

In other words, I want a.com to behave completely like b.com while still showing "a.com".

Answer (score 0):

You could create a .htaccess in root of your host web file reportory for each web site to redirect users